# init/2 undefined in cowboy hello_handler

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I am following https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/getting_started/

when I run

`gmake new t=cowboy_http n=hello_handler`

this creates src/hello_handler

```
-module(hello_handler).
-behaviour(cowboy_http_handler).

-export([init/3]).
-export([handle/2]).
-export([terminate/3]).

-record(state, {
}).

init(_, Req, _Opts) ->
    {ok, Req, #state{}}.

handle(Req, State=#state{}) ->
    {ok, Req2} = cowboy_req:reply(200, Req),
    {ok, Req2, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _Req, _State) ->
    ok.
```

the instructions says to modify init/2 but there is only init/3. Is this documentation outdated.. ?

Comment: It looks like `erlang.mk` has an outdated.[link](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy/issues/994)

Comment: Thank you! That works for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you are looking at does not match the version of cowboy you are looking at. The docs are for version 2.x, the handler is for version 1.x.

The Cowboy 1.x series implements an http handler with a behavior. When you generated a handler from a template, that handler implements that behavior.

However, in Cowboy 2.x, the handler only needs to implement `init/2`, and doesn't need to implement the behavior anymore.

When you check out Cowboy, you can make the docs for it with `make docs`. You can then browse them locally in `doc`. That way, you are guaranteed to have docs that match your version of cowboy.